# Unable to send error log email using smptlib and loggings, Python

Tags: python-2.7, email, logging, smtplib

Hi I am trying to send an email to myself when an exception is raised. However I am getting an exception I don't know how to solve. Here is the code and exception. I have tried all SO answers but in vain

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import smtplib

s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
s.login('xyz@gmail.com', 'myPassword')
s.starttls()

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(s)

try:
    a = 2/0
except Exception as e:
  logger.exception('Unhandled Exception')
  s.sendmail('xyz@gmail.com', 'xyz@gmail.com', 'Hi')
  s.close()
```

***ERROR LOG:***

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "try.py", line 5, in
>   
>       s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 788, in **init**
>       SMTP.**init**(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in **init**
>       (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
>       self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 794, in _get_socket
>       new_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(new_socket, self.keyfile, self.certfile)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 487, in wrap_socket
>       ciphers=ciphers)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 243, in **init**
>       self.do_handshake()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake()
>
> ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:140770FC:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**587** is a non-SSL port and hence `SMTP_SSL` call is failing. Try using port **465** as

`smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)`

or use the method for port 587

`smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)`